# How to emit an even from react hook component in typescript？

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, eventemitter

I have an component like:

```
<div>
<button onClick={add_input_list()}>add</botton>
<ul>
<li>
<input type="text" value={value} onChange={somefunction}/>
</li>
<li>
<input type="text" value= {value} onChange={somefunction}/>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I just want to make this component as children component which can emit this input onChange event to outside as onChange event.

But the  or  component do not have onChange event. How to add it?
I need the dive component have onChange event emmit. if input have onChange event and div will emit onChange event outside.

the full code similiar like:

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-codesandbox-template-forked-0hrdu?file=/index.js

Answer (score 2):

Since you wanted a list of input, here is the updated code. The Stackblitz example is updated as well :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const handleChange = inputListState => {
    console.log("Input list state = ", inputListState);
  };
  return <MyInputList onChange={handleChange} />;
};

const MyInputList = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState();
  
  // When state changes, emit the value to the parent
  React.useEffect(() => {
    onChange(state);
  }, [state]);
  
  const editState = e => {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input name="input1" type="text" onChange={editState} />
      </li>
      <li>
        <input name="input2" type="text" onChange={editState} />
      </li>
      <li>
        <input name="input3" type="text" onChange={editState} />
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is [the repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-yc9tua).

You just pass a method of the parent as prop to the child component and you use it in the `onChange` event of the input.

[edit]: for a list of input it works the same, but you justneed to build an object containing the different input states before to emit your value.

Comment: hi, actually, I need input list, so what I want is the <ul onchange={onchange}><li><input type="text"/></li></ul>, but the ul component do not have on change event. @Quentin Grisel